# How to obtain these monitor metrics from a server in Sybase ASE 16?

Tags: sybase, metrics, monitor

I have a database hosted on a server. And I have to monitor the database with a script with the necessary queries and stored procedures. The metrics that I have to monitor are:

- accounts or users are connected
- transactions are activated
- resources use transactions
- what time
- Processor use
- Disk use

They told me that with MDA tables I can do it. How can I get those metrics with these MDA ASE tables? Or with what stored procedures could I obtain them?

Comment: Welcome! It seems to me that these procedures have likely already been written for you. Try consulting the Sybase documentation, which would probably yield the information you require.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about full functionality of a full featured program. There are commercial tools available - like Bradmark Surveilance, or free - like asetune. You can also write your own scripts.

You could be using build in procedures like sp_sysmon. Or you can write your own scripts that read MDA tables and store the results. You can also try to use the tools delivered with ASE server - like ASE cockpit, Sybase Control Center (older versions), or Sybase Central (ancient ASE versions).

Answer (score 0):

One tool in Sybase that may be very helpful is sp_help table_name (just replace table_name with the name of the table you want to know more about). sp_help will show you everything you need to know about the tables, and columns in your database, and I've found it extremely helpful when I need to build queries, but can't remember the full structure of all the tables.

Once you have an idea of what values are stored where, you can build queries that will pull the information you need. As @Adam point out in his answer above, Sybase has built-in procedures that will gather at least some of this data. The Sybase InfoCenter is also a great source of information about what's available to you already.